# Foreground service is sometimes restarting and sometimes never starts when app is removed from open apps

Tags: java, android, cordova

I am implementing location tracker from Android app by using foreground service.
The expectation is the foreground service should run even

1. when app is removed from recent open apps.
2. When app is in open/foreground.
3. When app is in background i.e. app is still open but went to background

The case 2 & 3 are working fine but case 1 is working weirdly.

In case 1, sometimes foreground service is getting restarted (notification is going off and coming back) after few seconds i.e. 1 to 3 seconds.
In some other times it is never restarted.

I want the foreground service to never go off. In short, I want it like whatsapp location tracking. The whatsapp tracking icon never goes off when the app is closed.

Please give any pointers on what else I am missing

**Activity class**

```
public void enableTracking(String planId, JSONArray trackList, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    Log.i(TAG,"In enableTracking");
    Intent intent = new 
    Intent(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),LocationTracker.class);
   
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      cordova.getActivity().startForegroundService(intent);
      callbackContext.success("Location Tracking is enabled");
    } else {
      callbackContext.error("Build version is less than OREO");
    }
  }

public void disableTracking(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    Log.i(TAG,"In disableTracking");
    Intent intent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),LocationTracker.class);
    cordova.getActivity().stopService(intent);
    callbackContext.success("Location Tracking is disabled");
  }
```

**Service class**

```
public class LocationTracker extends Service {
  private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
  private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "2";
  private static final String TAG = "LocationTracker";
  private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
  RequestQueue mRequestQueue;


  public LocationTracker() {
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
  }

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onTaskRemoved");
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    buildNotification();   
    // logic to start location tracking
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // logic to stop tracking
  }


  private void fetchAndSendLocation() {
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {      
      Log.e(TAG, "No permission to fetch location");
      return;
    }
    // mFusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation()
    Task fetchLocTask = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    fetchLocTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Object o) {
        Location loc = (Location) o;
        if (loc != null) {
          Log.i(TAG, "Lat " + loc.getLatitude() + " lon " + loc.getLongitude() + " date " + (new Date()).toString());
          postLocation(loc);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void buildNotification() {
    String stop = "stop";
    PendingIntent broadcastIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this, 0, new Intent(stop), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Create the persistent notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setContentText("Location tracking is working")
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(broadcastIntent);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, getString(R.string.app_name),
          NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
      channel.setShowBadge(false);
      channel.setDescription("Location tracking is in progress");
      channel.setSound(null, null);
      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
    startForeground(1, builder.build());
  }
  
  public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public LocationTracker getService() {
      return LocationTracker.this;
    }
  }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:foregroundServiceType="location" android:name=".LocationTracker" />
```

Comment: "The whatsapp tracking icon never goes off when the app is closed." Then you need background location service...

Answer (score 0):

Using LocationManager as in code below has solved this similar situation for me.

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service {
private static final String TAG = "MyLocationService";
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 1000;
private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 10f;

private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    Location mLastLocation;

    public LocationListener(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
        mLastLocation = new Location(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
        mLastLocation.set(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
    }
}

LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[]{
        new LocationListener(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)
};

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");

    initializeLocationManager();

    try {
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,
                LOCATION_INTERVAL,
                LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                mLocationListeners[0]
        );
    } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
            try {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listener, ignore", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void initializeLocationManager() {
    Log.e(TAG, "initializeLocationManager - LOCATION_INTERVAL: "+ LOCATION_INTERVAL + " LOCATION_DISTANCE: " + LOCATION_DISTANCE);
    if (mLocationManager == null) {
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

}

You could modify this to suit your need.